# What video editing software should I use to make screencast videos with external audio?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, video, screencast, desktop-recording

I want to make screencast videos and record audio externally. What video editing software should I use? This is for an online class in introductory logic that I'm terribly late putting together.

To clarify: I want to record external audio, not internal. I want to highlight lines in a PDF while talking about the material.

I tried recordMyDesktop but it doesn't seem to have an external audio option.

Comment: This tutorial did it: https://www.linux.com/learn/how-make-youtube-instructional-screencast-video-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missed it, but **recordMyDesktop** *does* have the option to capture audio from your input device.

Once you launch recordMyDesktop, you should see a window similar to the following one:

[image]

You just need to check the box next to '*Sound Quality*'. Then it will capture the audio from your microphone along with capturing the desktop.

---

In order convert the file format to something *YouTube friendly* you may use OpenShot which provides some templates for YouTube friendly output (refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/45163/480481)).

Comment: Thank you! The videos come out terrible with recordMyDesktop though (half of the recordMyDesktop frame stays in the picture, and when I scroll down in the pdf it gets blurred). Do you know I can fix this? Should I ask a new question here in the forum?

Comment: @MartinSwanson It's better to ask a new question, perhaps with link to some problematic videos.