# Extract (rip) DVD in Chapters and not in Title

Tags: dvd

I'm ripping a Mozart DVD, but I only need to extract a few chapters (tracks) from it. I try to use dvdrip but it only extracts me the Title (the whole video). Is there any program to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several applications that allow you to do that, as I listed in a previous answer, see here: [What is the best tool for converting and reading video to be played on DVD players?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28079/what-is-the-best-tool-for-converting-and-reading-video-to-be-played-on-dvd-player/28104#28104)

Of those, I have successfully tested [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) for that and other purposes.

[image]

Give it a try and let us know how did you manage this situation.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! It works great, but I have a question.
It says: Chapters 1 trough 8, so it cuts the tracks automatically?

Comment: Nice to know you succeeded... Yes it does... you will get individual video files for each track as you request.

Comment: unluckily, HandBrake does not have an Oneiric release yet..

Comment: + there's no 64-bit version

Comment: Not listed but handbrake is installing and running perfectly on 64 bit systems using the ppa information provided right here: https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases

Answer (score 2):

try dvd ogmrip, you can choose the chapters you want

Comment: `ogmrip` managed to extract everything perfectly from a troublesome DVD, which failed when used with 3 other tools.